# Including a javascript file whe when creating a wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am developing a wordpress plugin and cannot get the javascript file to run. My javascript file looks like this:

```
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        alert("Javascript is running");
    });

</script>
```

This is the code in the main plugin php file where I am trying to load the scripts:

```
function super_plugin_scripts() {

    wp_register_script('super_plugin_script', get_template_directory_uri().'js/super-plugin.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('super_plugin_script');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'super_plugin_scripts');
```

I have also tried to run those two statements in the initialisation function but no luck.

Comment: Is anything showing in the console for failing to load?

Comment: Just had a look, the get_template_directory returns the directory of the theme and not the plugin so thats probably why its not finding it

Comment: Tried using plugin_dir_path and plugin_url but neither return the path to the folder that the plugin is actually held in. plugin_url returns the plugin folder in the wordpress file structure

Comment: See my answer below. Just saw you've fixed it already but that isn't very modular and you will need to change the folder name each time compared to running `plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)`

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript file should include raw js code, and no markup [so no `<script>` tag, but just its content].

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. make sure the path is right
2. make sure jQuery is included in your WordPress, if not add this line `wp_enqueue_script('jQuery');`

like this

```
    function super_plugin_scripts() {
        wp_register_script('super_plugin_script', get_template_directory_uri().'js/super-    plugin.js');

        wp_enqueue_script('jQuery');
        wp_enqueue_script('super_plugin_script');
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'super_plugin_scripts');
```

Comment: jQuery is definitely included, if I run the script in the header.php file it executes fine. The path is also correct, tried adding a '/' before 'js/' and still no luck.

Comment: i noticed you've found a solutions to your problem, it seems like the path was wrong after all :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a plugin and not a theme so try this out:

```
function super_plugin_scripts() {

    wp_register_script('super_plugin_script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'js/super-plugin.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('super_plugin_script');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'super_plugin_scripts');
```

`plugin_dir_url` requires you to pass in `__FILE__` and it should figure out the path.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix the problem. Used the plugins_url() function and then appended the name of the plugin to the front of the javascript file path like so:

```
wp_register_script('super_plugin_script', plugins_url().'/super-plugin/js/super-plugin.js');
```

Thanks!